# Updating Datatables with new Data

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

So I have a PHP script that queries a database, and outputs JSON. The query is something like so

```
SELECT year AS 'label', SUM(size) AS 'value'
FROM db.dbo.table
GROUP BY year
```

This adds up the size of each item made in the respective year, and displays the total sum for all years in a Datatable. I made a dropdown box that shows all of the years, like so

```
$.getJSON('script.php', function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;

    html += '<option value=' + 1 + '>All</option>';

    for (var i = 2; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value=' + i + '>' + data[i].label + '</option>';
    }

    $('select#list').append(html);
});
```

What I want to do is when the user selects a year, it updates the Datatable with all of the individual objects that were made in that year. This would require new columns. Here is my PHP.

```
<?php
$myServer = "server";
$myDB = "db";

$conn = sqlsrv_connect ($myServer, array('Database'=>$myDB));

$sql ="SELECT year AS 'label', SUM(size) AS 'value'
FROM db.dbo.table
GROUP BY year";

$data = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $sql);   
$result = array();   

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;   
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($data));

echo json_encode ($result);

sqlsrv_free_stmt ($data);
sqlsrv_close ($conn);
?>
```

Here is my initialization code

```
var oTable = $('#chart').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": "script.php",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "aoColumns": [ 
        { "mData": "label", "sClass": "center" },
        { "mData": "value", "sClass": "center" }
    ],

    "sDom": 'T<"clear">Rlfrtip',
    "oTableTools": { 
        "sSwfPath": "/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "sRowSelect": "multi", 
        "aButtons": ["select_all", "select_none", 
            {
            "sExtends": "collection",
            "sButtonText": "Export Selected Rows",
            "aButtons": [
                    { "sExtends": "copy", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [ 0, 1 ] },
                    { "sExtends": "csv", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [ 0, 1 ], "bFooter": false },
                    { "sExtends": "xls", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [ 0, 1 ], "bFooter": false },
                    { "sExtends": "pdf", "bSelectedOnly": true, "mColumns": [ 0, 1 ], "bFooter": false },
                ]
        },
            { "sExtends": "print", "sButtonText": "Print View" }
        ]
    }
});
```

And my HTML for the original query (where the sizes are summed)

```
<table id="chart" style="clear: both">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>year</th>
            <th>size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>year</th>
            <th>size</th>
        </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

I'm running into a few problems. The columns are coded into the HTML page, and I don't know how to change them. I also have no idea how to update the query on the PHP script so that it shows the new information when they click an option. I'm assuming I'm going to have to use [fnReloadAjax](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax), but I don't actually know.

Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

---

I have added the code for fnReloadAjax before the initialization, and added

```
$(document).on('change', '#list', function (event) {
    oTable.fnReloadAjax();
});
```

after the initialization. This is reloading the table properly. However, I need to change the query. I tried using David's code for aoData and $selectedYear, but I don't know enough PHP to get it to do what I want. Another thing is that there is also an All option in the drop down. So when the user first picks a year, it will completely change the table. However, it needs to be able to get back to the list of years in the original table

---

I tried to put the select statement in a `<form>`, like so

```
<form method="post" style="display: inline-block">
    <select name="value" id="list"></select>
</form>
```

And using `$selectedValue = $_POST['value'];` in the PHP file to use the selected value as a variable. I then trying to use an if statement to choose what query to use (if all, then query 1, else, query 2). However, this does not work

```
if ($selectedValue == "All") {
    $sql ="SELECT year AS 'label', SUM(size) AS 'value'
       FROM db.dbo.table
       GROUP BY year";
} else {
    $sql ="SELECT *
       FROM db.dbo.table"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your datatables initialisation you are missing some quite important initialisation properties that are vital to smooth server side operation of datatables, `bServerSide` being one of the most important.

Have a look at the docs for [server side here](https://datatables.net/usage/server-side)

Aside, and back to your question you have a number of callbacks that can be used with datatables to do this very thing. First and foremost:

```
fnServerParams(aoData)
```

this is used to send extra data to the server each time datatables makes an ajax request for new data.

```
var oTable = $("#chart").dataTable({
    bServerSide : true,
    fnServerParams : function(aoData) {
        // Push an object to the aoData array to make it available server side
        aoData.push({"name" : "year", "value" : $('#list')[0].value});
    }
}
```

Within script.php

```
$selectedYear = $_REQUEST['year'];
```

you can now use that in your SQL query to limit results to that year.

Another very useful datatable function is `fnDraw()`. This forces the datatable to update when it is called on the datatable object, sending any changed parameters with it.

```
var oTable = $('#chart').dataTable({ ... });

$(document).on('change', '#list', function(event) {
    oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

Comment: I tried to get server side to work when I first was making the Datatable, but I couldn't do it. What would would the initialization be to get that working? Also, I know very little PHP, so what would I do with $selectedYear in that file?

Comment: Can I not just use fnReloadAjax();? Using your last bit of code, and changing fnDraw to fnReloadAjax, it is reloading the data when the user selects a year. I just need to get it to change the query when it reloads.